# How to create a custom permalink structure for taxonomies in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I`m trying to achieve the following structure in urls for CPT`s:

- website.com/CPT - Lists all  - **OK**
- website.com/CPT/post-slug - List the CPT with slug - **OK**
- website.com/CPT/tags - Lists all tags used in the CPT - **Not working**
- website.com/CPT/tags/slug - Lists all CPT with tag with slug - **Not Working**

The tag here is a custom taxonomy created for the custom post type.

Has anyone that achieved this with success give some example?

My code is something like this:

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-portfolio',
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'rewrite'     => array(
          'slug'      => 'portfolio', 
          'with_front'  => false
      )
    )
);

register_taxonomy(
    'portfolio_tags',  
    'portfolio',       //post type name
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Tags'
        ),
        'hierarchical'    => false,
        'rewrite'           => array( 
            'slug' => 'portfolio/tags'
         ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the tag archive (website.com/CPT/tags/slug) I got it working by just declaring the taxonomy **BEFORE** the custom post type.

Now I`m trying to figure out the tags *index* that should list all tags.